Analysis of する間も与えずに

ハリーがそれ以上何か言ったり考えたりする間も与えずに、寝室のドアが勢いよく開いて双子のフレッドとジョージが入ってきた。
Before Harry had the time to say or think anything else, the bedroom door burst open and the twins, Fred and George, came in.

I'm having trouble understanding the 間も与えずに part.
First, is 間 pronounced あいだ here?
Second, why 間 and not 時間? What difference does this make?
Finally, who is doing the 'granting' in 与えずに?　I would have expected this to be in passive voice. An awkward English translation would be "without even being granted the time to ...".

I would have to read the door as the subject. If I wanted Fred and George to be the subjects, I would change it to 寝室のドアを勢いよく開けて.

@aguijonazo You think this sentence is a little awkward then?

Yes, I do. It sounds like an awkward translation from a language in which inanimate subjects are more common than in Japanese, such as English. It could have been 〜する間もなく.

This 間 is pronounced ま and means "time". If you know the phrase 間もなく, it's the same 間 here. The literal meaning of ～する間も与えずに is "without even giving time to do ～". In this sentence, Fred and George are the subjects of 与える, meaning they didn't give Harry enough time to think.
This 間 is indeed interchangeable with 時間, but 間 is more common in this context. This is a matter of convention or collocation.
